# how to access object properties from TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm new to Angular and TypeScript and just started working on a project using MEAN stack (MongoDB, Express, Angular, Node.js).

I created this mongoose module :

```
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const entrepriseSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {type: String, unique: true, required : true},
  telephone: Number,
  logo: String,
  web_site: String,
  sites: [
    {site_id: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Site'}}
  ]
});

const Entreprise = mongoose.model('Entreprise', entrepriseSchema);

export default Entreprise;
```

and this is my entreprise.component.ts :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

import { EntrepriseService } from '../services/entreprise.service';
import { SiteService } from '../services/site.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-entreprise',
  templateUrl: './entreprise.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./entreprise.component.scss'],
  providers: [EntrepriseService, SiteService]
})
export class EntrepriseComponent implements OnInit {


  entreprise = {};
  sites = [];
  id: String;

  constructor(private entrepriseService: EntrepriseService,
              private siteService: SiteService,
              private http: Http,
              private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.id = route.snapshot.params['id'];
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getEntrepriseById(this.id);
    //not working
    //console.log(this.entreprise.name);
    //console.log(this.entreprise.sites);
    //this.getSitesIn(this.entreprise.sites);
  }

  getEntrepriseById(id) {
    this.entrepriseService.getEntreprise(id).subscribe(
      data => this.entreprise = data,
      error => console.log(error)
    );
  }

  getSitesIn(ids) {
    this.siteService.getSitesIn(ids).subscribe(
      data => this.sites = data,
      error => console.log(error)
    );
  }
}
```

when I try to display the properties of the returned from entreprise.component.html it works fine and displays all the properties :

```
  <h3>{{entreprise.name}}</h3>
       <div *ngFor="let site of entreprise.sites">
         {{site.site_id}}
       </div>
         {{entreprise.logo}}
         {{entreprise.web_site}}
```

but how can I access the same properties on the TypeScript side ? 
The commented code in the EntrepriseComponent is what I'm trying to accomplish but it's not working since `this.entreprise` is type {} .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an Observable/http/async call in angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43055706/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-observable-http-async-call-in-angular2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Enterprise` model/schema that you created in Mongoose in Node.js resides on the server side. If you want the TypeScript code on the UI to recognize the properties in `Enterprise`, you will have to create a class in your angular codebase.

Create a folder named, say, `models` at the same level as your `services` folder. (Optional)

Create two files named site.ts and enterprise.ts in the `models` folder created in the previous step (You can put these file at a different location if you want) with the following contents:

**site.ts**

```
export interface Site {
 site_id?: string;
}
```

**enterprise.ts**

```
import { Site } from './site';
export interface Enterprise {
 name?: string;
 telephone?: string;
 logo?: string;
 web_site?: string;
 sites?: Site[];
}
```

Now, inside the `EntrepriseComponent` file, add the following imports

```
import { Enterprise} from '../models/entreprise';
import { Site } from '../models/site';
```

And change the first lines inside the `EntrepriseComponent` file to

```
export class EntrepriseComponent implements OnInit {

  entreprise: Enterprise = {};
  sites: Site[] = [];
```

Now, the enterprise attribute will be of type `Enterprise` and you will be able to access the properties that we declared in the `enterprise.ts` file.

**Update:**
Also, you cannot `console.log(this.enterprise.name)` immediately after `this.getEntrepriseById(this.id);` in your `ngOnInit()` function. This is because the web service you are making to get the enterprise object would not have resolved when you are trying to log it to the console.

If you want to see the enterprise object in the console or you want to run some code that needs to run after the service call has resolved and the `this.enterprise` object has a value, the best place to do this would be your `getEntrepriseById` function. Change the `getEntrepriseById` function to

```
  getEntrepriseById(id) {
    this.entrepriseService.getEntreprise(id).subscribe(
      data => {
           this.enterprise = data;
           console.log(this.enterprise.name);
           // Any code to run after this.enterprise resolves can go here.
      },
      error => console.log(error)
    );
  }
```

Comment: I am trying that but I can't  use ` entreprise: Enterprise = {};` it gives an error I tried `entreprise: Enterprise;` but then I get an error on the HTML `{{entreprise.name}}` I also tried ` entreprise= Enterprise()` but I get **undefined** in the console.log

Comment: `entreprise: Enterprise = {}` will not work because you are trying to create an Enterprise object without any of the properties that we declared in the Enterprise class. If you want to be able to do this, you should change the Enterprise class into an interface and mark the properties as optional. Let me update my answer with this.

Comment: In my answer, I've updated the contents of both `site.ts` and `enterprise.ts` to make them interfaces with all optional attributes.

Comment: I'm still getting undefined on the log. the HTML code works `{{entreprise.name}}` but the back-end is not `console.log(this.entreprise.name);`

Comment: I see what you are trying to do. Let me add an update in my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. I get it now, migrating from Java to Angular, I forgot it was asynchronous. ( you should just edit `this.enterprise.name` to `data.name`.